# Hibernate OneToMany returning two objects when there is only one in the database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a project with Hibernate and I'm having a pretty weird behaviour. In my database there are two entities Worksheet and WorksheetField. Saved in the database I have one worksheet and one field linked to it. When I get this entry from the database it comes with 2 fields.

My Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "worksheet")
public class Worksheet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    // .......
    
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = WorksheetField.class,
            mappedBy = "worksheet",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List<WorksheetField> fields;    
    
    // .......
    
}   


@Entity
@Table(name = "worksheet_field")
public class WorksheetField implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    // .......
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="worksheet_id",nullable = false)
    private Worksheet worksheet;    
    
    // .......
    
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface WorksheetRepository extends JpaRepository<Worksheet, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Worksheet> {

    List<Worksheet> findAllByWorksheetType(Worksheet.Type type);

    @Override
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    Worksheet save(Worksheet worksheet);

    @Override
    @Transactional
    Worksheet findOne(Long id);
}
```

The `@Transactional` on `findOne` is just an attempt at fixing this, don't worry about that. And I fetch this entry by using `findOne`.

Looking at these, is it possible to identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is just pure speculation on my part, but you could try changing `private List<WorksheetField> fields` to use a `Set` instead of a List. Hibernate sometimes has problems when fetching lists, especially multiple lists from an object because the way it constructs its joins somehow makes it hard for it to detect duplicates (Thats why you'll get org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException when trying to fetch multiple List belonging to an entity).

Comment: It would help to have your database schema and the relevant data from the tables.

Comment: Do you have other `OneToMany` relations in `Worksheet`? You can enable SQL logging and run generated SQL manually to check results.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I think it worked. I used Set instead of List and it seems OK. Thanks!

Comment: the problem remain why are you still getting 2 items when1 is present, using set in not solution!